# Eclipse format only specific annotations

Tags: eclipse, format

I have this code:

```
public class Rarities extends FXMLView {

    @FXML
    Button btnCreate;

    @FXML
    Button btnDelete;

    @FXML
    TableColumn<Rarity, Color> tbcColor;

    @FXML
    TableColumn<Rarity, Number> tbcId;

    @FXML
    TableColumn<Rarity, String> tbcName;

    @FXML
    TextField txtFilter;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @FXML
    void create(ActionEvent event) {

    }

    @FXML
    void delete(ActionEvent event) {

    }
    
}
```

I want it to be formatted this way.

```
public class Rarities extends FXMLView {

    @FXML Button btnCreate;
    @FXML Button btnDelete;
    @FXML TableColumn<Rarity, Color> tbcColor;
    @FXML TableColumn<Rarity, Number> tbcId;
    @FXML TableColumn<Rarity, String> tbcName;
    @FXML TextField txtFilter;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @FXML void create(ActionEvent event) {

    }

    @FXML void delete(ActionEvent event) {

    }
    
}
```

I want only @FXML annotated elements to be formatted like. I have more files like this with more fields and it's never ending scroll down.

I'm using Eclipse's formatter tool.

[image]

I'm just curious if such exception is possible.

Answer (score 0):

It's apprently not possible to write custom formatting rules but it could be easily done with `File Search` (Ctrl + H) tool and the `Replace` feature using this regular expression:
`(?m)(@FXML)\s*\n\s+(.*)\n`

[image]

On the replace box use `$1 $2\n` as replacement
`$1` represents the first capturing group (`@FXML`) and `$2` represents the following line

[image]